# Is there a way to import a gemcraft chasing shadows save into steam?

Tags: steam, gemcraft-chasing-shadows

I just found out that Gemcraft Chasing Shadows was available on steam and being a Gemcraft fan I bought it. I have extensively played the game on it's original home of armour games and still have the online save linked directly to my armour games account. Is there any way I can import that game data into the steam version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steam game is not just a port of the armor games version. The developers had to make architectural changes and the save file structure is completely different.

Therefore you're unable to import your save file. The developers have also stated they're not adding a save import function.